# How to parse data from 2 different URLs by asyncTask method

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, return

I have an app that get data from a JSON URL. It works perfectly with one URL, but I need to get data from two JSON URLs at the same time. Like some data from one URL and some from the other one. And show them in two textViews.

Here is my app, it does not load any data currently.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url1 = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/de?format=json";
private static String url2 = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/it?format=json";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String CountryNAME1 = "name";
private static final String CountryNAME2 = "name";
JSONArray user = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new GetJSONTask().execute(url1);
    //new GETJSONTask().execute(url2);
}
class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {


    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Creating new JSON Parser
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
        JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);

        return json1;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json1, JSONObject json2) {
        //Getting JSON Array
        try {

            //For Country 1
            // Get the array
            JSONArray countryArC1 = json1.getJSONArray("myValues");
            JSONObject countryObC1 = countryArC1.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray countryAr2C1 = countryArC1.getJSONArray(1);
            JSONObject countryOb2C1 = countryAr2C1.getJSONObject(0);

            //For Country 2
         // Get the array
            JSONArray countryArC2 = json2.getJSONArray("myValues");
            JSONObject countryObC2 = countryArC2.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONArray countryAr2C2 = countryArC2.getJSONArray(1);
            JSONObject countryOb2C2 = countryAr2C2.getJSONObject(0);




            //Storing JSON item in a Variable
            String name1 = countryOb2C1.getString(CountryNAME1);
            String name2 = countryOb2C2.getString(CountryNAME2);

            //Importing TextView
            final TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.url1);
            final TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.url2);

            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            textView1.setText(name1);
            textView2.setText(name2);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**JSONParser:**

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    //System.out.println("url getJSONfromUrl " + url);
    //url = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/CA/indicators/SP.POP.TOTL?date=1980:1981&format=json";

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("JSONParser string: " + json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    if (json.startsWith("[")) {
        // We have a JSONArray
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject();
            jObj.put("data", new JSONArray(json));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("JSON Parser", "Error parsing JSONArray " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }

 // try parse the string to a JSON object
    /*try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }*/

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;



}
}
```

XML:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/url1"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
         />
```

I think the main problem is `new GetJSONTask().execute(url1);` and `JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);` As I cant have 2 GetJSONTASKs and also cant return json1 and json2 at the same time.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to change your method to

```
class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]> {

 ...

 protected JSONObject[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject[] jsons = new JSONObject[2];
    jsons[0] = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
    jsons[1] = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);

    return jsons;
}
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject[] jsons) {
    JSONObject json1 = jsons[0];
    JSONObject json2 = jsons[1];
    // do you work after this
}
}
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

**Variant A)** You could execute your `GetJSONTask` like this:

```
new GetJSONTask().execute(url1, url2);
```

And access the URLs in your AsyncTask like this:

```
 class GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]> {
     ...
     JSONObject[] doInBackground(String... urls) {

         // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[1]);
        JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2[2]);

        return new JSONObject[] {json1, json2};
    }

    void onPostExecute(JSONObject[] jsons) { ... }

}
```

**Variant B)** If you want to make the process running truly parallel, you could add another AsyncTask which creates 2 child Tasks and waits for their result. On most devices, this will half the time required to perform that task.

```
class GetTwoJsonsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]> {
    JSONObject[] doInBackground(urls) {

        task1 = new GetJSONTask().execute(urls[1]);
        task2 = new GetJSONTask().execute(urls[2]);

        // block until sub-tasks are finished
        JSONObject json1 = task1.get();
        JSONObject json2 = task2.get();

        return new JSONObject[] {json1, json2};
    }

    void onPostExecute(JSONObject[] jsons) { ... }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is a problem. It errors in this like `return new JSONObject[] {json1, json2};` and this is the reason: _Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONObject[] to JSONObject_

Comment: You need to provide the correct type in the generic AsyncTask: `GetJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject[]>`

Answer (score 0):

that's how i did it, it's in easy way to do it

```
public class GetSetting extends AsyncTask<List<String>,Void,List<String>> {

    String urls[] =  new String[]{"http:// first url",
                              "http:// second url"};


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(List<String>... lists) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        InputStream inputStream;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        URL urlIfSup;
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            // here to connect and get a different type of data  

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ // this one for connect the url from url array in every loop 

                urlIfSup = new URL(urls[i]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlIfSup.openConnection();
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"utf-8"));

                String data = bufferedReader.readLine();

                while(bufferedReader.readLine() != null){

                    data += bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
                if (i==0) {

                    // do something for the first url

                }else if (i==1){

                  // do something for the second url
                   // use jSON if you want 


                  // then do this at the last url       
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                    inputStream.close();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
}
```