# executing multiple urls in asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

How to Execute multiple URL's from single asynctask?. In my application I have four URL's. Iwant data of four URL's in a single GET request. How to get using AsyncTask in android

```
public class SOCreation extends AppCompatActivity  {

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

SalesOrganization salesOrganization = new SalesOrganization();
SalesDistribution salesDistribution = new SalesDistribution();
SoldToParty soldToParty = new SoldToParty();
Division division = new Division();

String[] ITEMS = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
MaterialSpinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3,spinner4,spinner5;

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
String qua="",mat="";

public static final  String url1 = "http://192.168.1.5:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_APP_SRV/SaleOrgSet?$format=json";
public static final  String url2 = "http://192.168.1.5:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_APP_SRV/DistrChannelSet?$filter=SalesOrg%20eq%20%271020%27&$format=json";
public static final  String url3 = "http://192.168.1.5:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_APP_SRV/DivsnSet?$filter=SalesOrg%20eq%20%271020%27%20and%20DistChannel%20eq%20%2720%27&$format=json";
public static final  String url4 = "http://192.168.1.5:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_APP_SRV/CustomersSet?$filter=SalesOrg%20eq%20%271020%27%20and%20DistrChannel%20eq%20%2720%27%20and%20Division%20eq%20%2700%27&$format=json";

String authorizationString = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("abaper" + ":" + "erp@786").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_so_creation);

  new  GetAsync().execute(url1,url2,url3,url4);
```

public class GetAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String line = "", response = "";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[1]);
            JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[2]);
            JSONObject json3 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[3]);
            JSONObject json4 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urls[4]);

                    URL urlToken = new URL("http://192.168.1.5:8002/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZSALES_APP_SRV/");
                    String token = new TokenGeneration().getToken(authorizationString, urlToken);

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationString);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239386/how-to-parse-data-from-2-different-urls-by-asynctask-method

Answer (score 1):

use **Volley**.It Supports multiple request at a time.

**1. Create 4 Boolean variable for each web service. 2. if you get any response from web service 1 then store to global variable and set Boolean 1 to true and so on for you 4 request. 3. when web-service completed send the work flow to a common function and there you can check the Boolean variables.if all variable's are equal to true then do what you want with your response.**

Comment: Can you please share the code which suits for my problem??

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting data from SAP Gateway, use $batch method to group your 4 requests in a single request. Code sample and documentation is available at https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/94/a126519eff236ee10000000a445394/content.htm