# Android / JSON return object from two JSON URLS in same activity

Tags: java, android, json, url, android-asynctask

This is code:

```
@Override
        protected DVLAInformation doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String dvlaNumFin = intent.getStringExtra("dvlaNumber");

                final URL url = new URL("https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=" + dvlaNumFin + "&apikey=");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();

                DVLAInformation obj = new DVLAInformation(url.toString());
                obj.readAndParseJSON(responseOutput.toString());



                return obj;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;


        }
```

My question is how to return object from two JSON URL in same activity

For example is I will have two urls

```
final URL url = new URL("https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/DvlaSearch?licencePlate=" + dvlaNumFin + "&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

final URL url2 = new URL("https://dvlasearch.appspot.com/MotHistory?licencePlate=mt09nks&apikey=DvlaSearchDemoAccount");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

And I do not know how to return something like this:

```
    DVLAInformation obj = new DVLAInformation(url.toString());
                    obj.readAndParseJSON(responseOutput.toString());
    DVLAInformation obj2 = new DVLAInformation(url2.toString());
                    obj2.readAndParseJSON(responseOutput.toString());

return obj, obj2
```

Sorry for my explanation, I know the way is incorrect, I just try to explain what I would like to do.

FOUND this [CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239386/how-to-parse-data-from-2-different-urls-by-asynctask-method) but do not understand how to apply it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). If you need guidance you may find this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) userful.

As an alternative you could use OkHttp and chain the HTTP requests.

Comment: is it any other way to do it? like create two AsyncTask or two doInBackground?

Comment: Yes but don't use AsyncTasks, they are only for short term operations, have a look at the [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class

Comment: This is what I need, as short term  operations

Comment: Found tutorial (added to post) but do not understand how to apply it.